# What was the first version of openssh to support patterns in AllowUsers and AllowGroups etc

Tags: linux

I would like to know if all version of openssh support pattern in directivies as allowusers and allowgroups and others

I need to setting this in many old linux servers in sshd_config

```
AllowUsers user0*@192.168.*.*
```

i tested this in redhat 6.3 and it work, but i don't know if i can do that with all openssh versions

Comment: What is the earliest version that you need support for?  It might be easier to simply install that version and test.  Past that you may have to go back and dig through the docs in included in the old source packages.

Comment: I have about 10 servers suse 8.1 with openssh-3.4p1-105, but i cannot test because are production systems

Comment: You can't spin up a virtual machine running suse 8.1 and test there?  On a more general note, it would be nice to have staging environments you can test things on before pushing to prod, something that matches what you have in prod, rather than a random RH 6.3 box.

Comment: In perfect world, in my job place we don't have a stagin evironments, i will try to looking around in internet for an old version of suse 8

Answer (score 2):

According to [CVS](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshd.8) [history](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshd_config.5), AllowUsers appears in one of the first versions of the sshd manpage, dated october 11 1999. This is just after the ssh fork, so I'm guessing that one supported it before the fork and all versions OpenSSH support it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed fedora core 2 using kvm, openssh version is "openssh-server-3.6.1p2-34", and i tried this in sshd_config AllowUsers !pip*@*, after reload the sshd daemon and i try to loggin using the user pippo, the result is this

```
"Dec 14 16:30:28 localhost sshd[2647]: User pippo not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers"
```

Now i think this work in any ssh versions